# Under UK law, what is the effect on inheritance tax liability of giving a gift back?

Tags: united-kingdom, gift-tax, inheritance

Scenario: a parent gives a gift to their child, but the child later gives the gift back. The parent then dies within 7 years of the original gift being given, and the child inherits the parent's estate (which includes the gift).

Does the child have to pay inheritance tax on the gifted amount twice? Once due to receiving the initial gift, and again due to inheriting the gift?

Or does giving the gift back cancel out any extra liability?

Comment: Is it even possible to "ungift" something by giving it back after it's been accepted? The parent has no rights to the gifted property anymore, it would seem that at this point it's just the child giving a gift to the parent. I'm not sure it wouldn't be considered a gift just because the parent had owned the item at some point in the past but doesn't anymore.

Comment: Perhaps a bonus question: if the gift changes hands in this way several times, is it possible for the IHT liability to grow without bound, exceeding the total estate value?

Comment: Would it not be possible to reclassify the gift as a loan in which case the IHT on the initial gift would not apply.